# Left outer join with Select clause in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to run this query on my SQLite database:

```
SELECT * FROM tag LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tag, annotation FROM annotation_tag_map WHERE annotation = ?) AS map ON tag._id = map.tag;
```

The ? is an ID for the annotation.

I am getting an empty cursor when I run this query in android.

However when I run it with sqlite3 from the command line on the same database I get the results I want.

Comment: try to print your runtime query in logcat and then copy and paste it in command line see results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your query  at runtime and put in command line that get Rsults ?

if yes then,,

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Your Query as a String,null);
```